# Sending an email to follow up with the client about a project deadline

Tags: word-choice, email, timelines

We are waiting on a document for a project from the client to complete. If we don't get it in 2 days we'll be unable to proceed until we do.

When and how do you follow up with the client? Give a timeframe and a sample script.

Answer (score 2):

#### Ask your manager

This depends on lots of things, such as how long you've been waiting, how often you communicate with the client anyway, how clear the communication was that you can't proceed, how far away your client is/ whether the client is in a different timezone, your work culture, their work culture,...

Writing now might be a good idea to give them a day to compile whatever it is that you need to proceed and to send it to you.

But the only way to make sure what to do is by asking your manager.

You need something in writing that shows that you did your job by asking what the right thing to do is. And you need to notify your client before the timeline ends, especially if you have been waiting for more than a couple days already. The client won't appreciate if you just suddenly and silently stop working.

You would simply follow up by mentioning what was stated in previous communications.

> This is a reminder about the upcoming timeline for the project xyz. Please send us the document on *stuff* within the next 48 hours so that we can continue working on feature x and deliver milestone y within 2 weeks. Without the document work on the feature can't continue.

The other formal stuff, like how to greet the client and how the style is in general (formal versus informal, short versus elaborate, ...) and other documents attached depend on the specific situation.